# Why does .iloc work but not .loc while indexing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

When I try to specify a row with an integer, it works fine, but when I try with a label I get the error "KeyError: 'Week 3'"

[file which is loaded](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IvDyH_jsRisKwLaGoyN2xBaTcbpyvmH2/view?usp=sharing)

```
df = pd.read_csv('Size_Breakdown_crosstab.csv', sep='\t')
df1 = df.loc["Week 3"]
df2 = df.iloc[3]
```

Comment: Specify `index_col` in your read_csv

Comment: `Period` is a column and not the index, so `loc` cannot find `Week 3` in your index. Use `df = pd.read_csv('Size_Breakdown_crosstab.csv', sep='\t', index_col='Period')`, then it should work correctly

Comment: Or `df.loc[df['Period'] == "Week 3"]` or `df.set_index('period'); df.loc["Week 3"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index labels are probably numerical, since by default `pandas.read_csv` adds a numerical index column to your DataFrame.

You need to explicitly state which column to use as an index, e.g.:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Size_Breakdown_crosstab.csv', sep='\t', index_col=0)
```

Which will treat the first column as the index column.